# Restrict remote page execution in classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

The title says it all, is it possible to do? Lets say I need to block access via MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP or any other object, also via ajax IF the request was not local and allow asp execution only on local machine. Is it need to be done in ASP or IIS 7 ?

Lets say we have this code:

```
url = "http://www.website.com" 
set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP") 
xmlhttp.open "GET", url, false 
xmlhttp.send "" 
Response.write xmlhttp.responseText 
set xmlhttp = nothing
```

Currently, my website is allowing this request from my local address at home, how to block such access?

thanks

Comment: Just bind this site to a local/internal IP address in IIS - it won't be accessible from the outside world

Comment: I think you didnt get it right. I need to block spammers/etc, not the whole world.

Comment: You might be right. I read it that you want to execute ASP only when request to these ASP pages come from the local machine. Bind the site to a local (not public) IP address and no one from the outside will be able to access these pages. Is this what you have in mind?

Comment: Ah, I see now. It would have been nice to specify this in the original text

Comment: Are you running your web site on your home machine or somewhere else? And another question - do you want to protect ALL ASP pages or just some of them (e.g. admin interface)

Comment: yeah, I edited it, so its clear for everyone. Basically, what I need is to block all manipulations from someone's home pc's and execute .asp pages at natural requests.

Comment: 1)my website is in another country. 2) All pages on the server, which one is easier to do?

Comment: and as a test you want to try to block access from your home computer, right?

Comment: surely, many websites dont load via that MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP object, and load only directly, thats what I need too.

Comment: You can still block access in IIS but a large block list is difficult to maintain. You can also block in code - in global.asa - Session_OnStart - I will provide an example

Answer (score 0):

You can also block in code - in global.asa - Edit your Session_OnStart event handler:

```
If request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR") = "insert your IP address here" Then
Session.Abandon
Response.End()
End If
```

Note: If someone connects via a proxy server you may see an IP address of the proxy instead. In some cases you may also want to interrogate the X-Forwarded-For header to see if a bad IP address is found there.